# Is there a keyboard shortcut to remove the selection on a webpage in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Tmux in my terminal and that means I am typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> a lot.

In Chrome when this happens it selects the entire page and turns it blue.

How can I undo this without having to switch to my mouse to click in the page again?

Comment: [Doesn't look](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77291) like your issue is getting much attention. Depending on whether you're willing to go there, you could consider switching browsers (e.g. Esc de-selects text in Opera), or using third-party software (e.g. keyboard software) to simiulate, say, a right-click followed by Esc, if you don't want to use Tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key works for me. This will move the cursor to the next selectable item but may not be an issue in your case.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. If you feel this solves your problem you can mark the question accepted.

Comment: Sure, I am still hoping to find an answer that does not scroll the page, though.